# Determinant of Hankel matrix with $a_n=(n!)^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinants, gamma-function, hankel-matrices

Consider a Hankel matrix of the form

$H_n(a_0(n))=\begin{pmatrix}
a_0(n) & (1!)^2 & (2!)^2 & \cdots & (n!)^2\\
(1!)^2 & (2!)^2 & (3!)^2& \cdots & ((n+1)!)^2\\
(2!)^2 & (3!)^2 & (4!)^2& \cdots & ((n+2)!)^2\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
(n!)^2 & ((n+1)!)^2 & ((n+2 )!)^2& \cdots & ((2n)!)^2
\end{pmatrix}.$

I would like to find (for a given $n$) the value of $\tilde{a}_0(n)$ such that $\operatorname{det}[H_n(\tilde{a}_0(n))]=0$.

In particular, I would like to know if

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \tilde{a}_0(n) = 1.$$

Is there a way of doing this?

To give an example of a similar problem with a known solution it is possible to show numerically that for a Hankel matrix like the one above but without the squares ($k!$ instead of $(k!)^2$) the value of $a_0$ for which the determinant is zero is $\tilde{a}_0(n) =\frac{n-1}{n}$. The problem with $(k!)^2$ however doesn't converge numerically to a simple answer.

Added note: Numerically one can find the value of $a_0(n)$ such that the determinant is null. This value tends to 1 (although softly since one can't take $n$ too large without running in to computational difficulties). For finite $n$ the value of $\det[H_n(1)]$ will be (as expected) very different than zero!

Comment: Numerical computations suggest that $\det(H_n(1))$ does not go to $0$.

Comment: @JosephVanName My numerical computations tell me that the more I increase $n_{max}$ the more  $a_0\rightarrow 1$ asymptotically (obviously for large $n_{max}$ the determinant computation starts taking a lot of time therefore also the value of 1 I gave is a suggestion..). May I ask how you found your result?

Comment: I just put the numbers into a computer algebra system to evaluate the determinant.

Comment: Sorry if I'm not getting you, but $a_0(n)\to 1$ and $\det(H_n(1))\to0$ are two _a priori_ different properties.

Comment: @JosephVanName what I am doing is computing for a given $n$ the value of $a_0$ so that the determinant vanishes, and this seems to tend to 1 (although as I said $n_{max}$ is an issue..

Comment: To help quantify @JosephVanName's comment: for n = 1, 2, 3 the determinants are 3, 656, and 58910976. By n = 13 the determinant is larger than 10^278

Comment: @OlivierBégassat I realize.. I would be happy to know the $n\rightarrow \infty$ limit, but if there is a general solution for $a_0(n)$ which can be shown to go to 1 when n goes to infinity it would be even better!

Comment: @NathanielJohnston yes, I see, but as I explained above another thing one can do is checking for a fixed value of $n$ what $a_0$ is needed for the determinant to be zero. Then one can show that this value approaches 1 asymptotically (although one needs very large $n_{max}$ to do so (I stopped at 500..). The reason it becomes larger than 10^278 is that the determinant is incredibly sensitive to the value of $a_0$. If one considers n=10 for example the solution for which the determinant is null is $a_0=0.833$. If you try and compute $\det[H_0(0.84)]$ it goes like 10^11..

Comment: The numerical issue is clearly taking large values of n. That is why I was wondering if there is an analytic way of showing this..

Comment: I assume $(n+1!)$ means $(n+1)!$ and so on for the last column

Comment: From a computational point of view it is perhaps best to replace $a_0$ by $1+x$. The determinant is then of the form $\alpha+\beta x$ (with $\alpha,\beta$ integers depending on $n$) and one can solve for $x$.
With this method one can work modulo many (not too) small primes and reconstruct $\alpha,\beta$ for larger values of $n$.

Comment: The limit for $a_0$ does not seem to exist.

Comment: @T.Amdeberhan did you prove this?

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but an explicit formula for $\tilde{a}_0(n)$ is $\tilde{a}_0(n) = v^T H_{2,n}^{-1} v$ where $v$ is the first column of $H_n$ without the first element, $v^T = \begin{bmatrix} (1!)^2 & \cdots & (n!)^2 \end{bmatrix}$, and $H_{2,n}$ is $H_n$ with the first row and column removed, i.e., the Hankel matrix with entries $(2!)^2, (3!)^2, \dotsc, (2n!)^2$.

Comment: $$1 - \tilde{a}_0(n) = \frac{\left| \begin{matrix}
1 & f(1) & f(2) & \cdots & f(n)\\
f(1) & f(2) & f(3)& \cdots & f(n+1)\\
f(2) & f(3) & f(4)& \cdots & f(n+2)\\
\cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
f(n) & f(n+1) & f(n+2) & \cdots & f(2n)\end{matrix} \right|}{\left| \begin{matrix}
f(2) & f(3) & \cdots & f(n+1)\\
f(3) & f(4) & \cdots & f(n+2)\\
\cdots & \cdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
f(n+1) & f(n+2) & \cdots & f(2n)\end{matrix} \right|}$$ with $f(m) = m!^2$, so perhaps the question should be what conditions on $f$ are sufficient for this to tend to zero.

Comment: Note that you can reduce the size of the numbers considerably by multiplying the matrices from Peter's comment with 
$ \mathrm{diag}[(j!)^{-2}]_{j=0,1}^n$ from both sides.
This leads to  binomials, 
$$1-\tilde a_0(n)= \frac
{\det \left[\left({i+j \atop j}\right)^2\right]_{i,j=0}^n}
{\det \left[\left({i+j \atop j}\right)^2\right]_{i,j=1}^n}\,.
$$
However, these matrices are not Hankel anymore.